# very high float value changing to infinity while retrieving from database

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have an entry in my database

```
select item_numeric_value from Item_Allowed_Values where id=761
```

datatype of `item_numeric_value` is `float` in my db.

the result I get is `1.11111111111111E+49`.

when I retrieve this value in java in a string , I get infinity.

is there anything I am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: What server version do you use? sql server or mysql!?

Comment: "retrieve this value in java in a string", any specific reason why you want to get a numeric value in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `double` instead of `float`:

```
    // Float.MAX_VALUE = 3.4028234663852886E38f
    float f = Float.parseFloat("1.11111111111111E+49");
    System.out.println("f=" + f);   // -> f=Infinity

    // Double.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157E308
    double d = Double.parseDouble("1.11111111111111E+49");
    System.out.println("d=" + d);   // -> d=1.11111111111111E49
```

Comment: I would avoid using double type. "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch explains why BigDecimal should be used rather than double. The chapter is called "Avoid float and double if exact answers are required" (Item #48 in the second edition of the book). It has some examples which show how doubles can easily corrupt results.